# SQL query help - find by groupID

Tags: sql-server

I have an ItemList table where there is a groupID column and an itemID column (which can be 1, 2 or 3).  What I'd like to do is return the data where the groupID has itemID's 1, 2 **AND** 3.

I'll illustrate below with some sample data:

```
GroupID       ItemID       

   1            1       
   2            1 
   2            2 
   2            3
   3            1
   3            2 
   4            1
   4            2
   4            3
   5            1
   5            2
```

And the data I'd like out of that would be:

```
GroupID       ItemID       

   2            1 
   2            2 
   2            3
   4            1
   4            2
   4            3
```

Any ideas how I'd achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EXISTS() queries to check the conditions, like so:

```
select i.GroupID, i.ItemID
from ItemList i
where 
exists (select 1 from ItemList where GroupID = i.GroupID and ItemID = 1)
and exists (select 1 from ItemList where GroupID = i.GroupID and ItemID = 2)
and exists (select 1 from ItemList where GroupID = i.GroupID and ItemID = 3)
order by i.GroupID, i.ItemID
```

Comment: That's great Fosco, thanks very much. I knew it had to be easy enough!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @T table
(
  GroupID int,
  ItemID int
)
insert into @T values       
(   1,            1),       
(   2,            1), 
(   2,            2),
(   2,            3),
(   3,            1),
(   3,            2), 
(   4,            1),
(   4,            2),
(   4,            3),
(   5,            1),
(   5,            2)

select GroupID, ItemID
from @T 
where GroupID in
  (
    select GroupID
    from @T
    group by GroupID
    having count(distinct ItemID) = 3
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `JOIN`'s (although I make no excuses for the performance) but it works ;-)

```
SELECT IL1.*
FROM ItemList IL1
INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupID FROM ItemList WHERE ItemID = 1) IL2
ON IL2.GroupID = IL1.GroupID
INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupID FROM ItemList WHERE ItemID = 2) IL3
ON IL3.GroupID = IL1.GroupID
INNER JOIN (SELECT GroupID FROM ItemList WHERE ItemID = 3) IL4
ON IL4.GroupID = IL1.GroupID
```